# if/else statement evaluating only else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

*Disclaimer: This is a question regarding an assignment for a Coursera course.*

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to create a new column that differentiates between weekdays and weekends in my data set. I'm using a nested if/else statement within a for loop. The problem is the output makes every row 'weekday'. Does anyone see something glaringly wrong with my code? My end goal is to create a new factor variable that is either "weekend" or "weekday."

```
df4 <- mutate(df4, day = weekdays(df4$date))
for (i in df4$day) {
    if(i %in% c("Saturday",'Sunday')) {
        df4$day_type <- 'weekend'
    } else {
        df4$day_type <- 'weekday'
    }
}
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized. You can simply do `ifelse(df4$day %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday'), 'weekend', 'weekday')`

Comment: In your for loop, you are reassigning the entire column `day_type` rather than just one element at a time. I suspect why you are seeing everything as "weekday" is because the last value in `day` is a weekday. You could try looping through the number of rows (`i in 1:nrow(df4)`) and then in your if else using `df4$day_type[i] `. But your best bet is probably Sotos' ifelse

Comment: ifelse worked. Gracias Sotos

Answer (score 0):

I modify a little bit of your code .(see below)

```
for (i in 1 : dim(df4)[1]) {
  if(df4$day[i] %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')) {
    df4$day_type[i] <- 'weekend'
  } else {
    df4$day_type[i] <- 'weekday'
  }
}
```